# How do I get stack to use dynamic linking?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm using `stack` to build projects and find that the generated executables are pretty large (10M) even for simple programs. In order to reduce the executable size, how can i get `stack` to build shared libraries and generate executables that dynamically link to shared libraries?

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/SharedLibraries/PlatformSupport and the `-ghc-options` parameter to `stack build`

Answer (score 9):

Add '-dynamic' to `ghc-options` in your .cabal file.

For example, in a project generated by `stack new simple-example simple`, the `simple` executable was 1.0M before adding '-dynamic' to `ghc-options`. It reduced to 12K after the change.

Here's the relevant part of the `simple-example.cabal`:

```
executable simple-example
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  main-is:             Main.hs
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
  ghc-options:         -dynamic
```

Build with `stack build` (no options are required).

To show which libraries it's dynamically linked against, you can use the `ldd` tool (or `otool -L` on Mac).

```
$ otool -L .stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-6.10/7.10.3/bin/simple-example
.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-6.10/7.10.3/bin/simple-example:
        @rpath/libHSbase-4.8.2.0-HQfYBxpPvuw8OunzQu6JGM-ghc7.10.3.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
        @rpath/libHSinteger-gmp-1.0.0.0-2aU3IZNMF9a7mQ0OzsZ0dS-ghc7.10.3.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
        @rpath/libHSghc-prim-0.4.0.0-8TmvWUcS1U1IKHT0levwg3-ghc7.10.3.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
        @rpath/libHSrts-ghc7.10.3.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
        @rpath/libffi.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.2.0)
        /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```